# Cómo imprimir 'nombre' en blanco por que sale en negro y mi fondo es negro?

Tags: php

Esta es la linea:

```
<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['nombre']); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

adicional/complementario para los echo por consola:

```
define( 'DG_LOG_TEXT_WHITE' , "\033[0m" );
define( 'DG_LOG_TEXT_GREEN' , "\033[32m" );
define( 'DG_LOG_TEXT_RED' , "\033[31m" );
define( 'DG_LOG_TEXT_MAGENTA' , "\033[35m" );
define( 'DG_LOG_TEXT_CYAN' , "\033[36m" );
define( 'DG_LOG_TEXT_YELLOW' , "\033[33m" );


echo DG_LOG_TEXT_WHITE. "texto blanco" . PHP_EOL;
echo DG_LOG_TEXT_YELLOW . "texto amarillo" . DG_LOG_TEXT_WHITE . PHP_EOL;
```

mas info de colores por consola:
[How to enable color for PHP CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34034730/1423096)

[ref 1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization)

[ref 2](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Pues debes poner ese php echo, en un elemento html por ejemplo un parrafo y darle el estilo:

```
<p style="color: white;"><?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['nombre']); ?></p>
```

Comment: gracias si me sirvio <3

Comment: Al votar negativo una respuesta vale más dejar un comentario especificando el por qué. @DeyviDeLaCruz tu respuesta resuelve en ambiente web y espero sea la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: @aloMalbarez la respuesta es bastante pobre, no hay ningún contexto explicado por el OP para responder de esta manera, y además plantea algunas prácticas que son consideradas malas. Ya que tanto dices conocer cómo funciona SO y que tienes una reputación aceptable, deberías darte cuenta con solo leerla, a menos que no conozcas nada de web, lo entendería.

Comment: @Shaz Es una respuesta simple a una pregunta simple, lo cual la hace general y puede servirle a más personas. Si te parece que puede ser mejorada sin perder el sentido ni hacerla tan específica que a nadie mas que al OP le sirva pues adelante: es un trabajo colaborativo.